# Why does Montouch not keep a managed reference from the UIView to its UIViewController?

Tags: uikit, xamarin.ios

According to Apple's documentation, the `nextRepsonder` property of `UIView` returns the connected UIViewController:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And if I look at UIView.h of SDK 5, I can see the following:

```
UIViewController *_viewDelegate;
```

For me this means: although Apple tells us that they are not coupled, they really are but we should not know and not care.

But if the non-managed world holds a reference, shouldn't Monotouch then hold a managed reference, too?

Wouldn't it simplify things a lot with regards to keeping references at class levels? Wouldn't it reduce common traps cause by GC'ed view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

> But if the non-managed world holds a reference

That assumption might be wrong (testing would prove it, if you doubt the documentation) because having a field does not provide enough evidence to state a reference is made on the native side.

After all ObjectiveC is not using a garbage collector, i.e. it's reference counted (even with ARC). So simply having a field in the type definition does not mean it keeps a *reference* (as in the .NET/GC world) to the `UIView`, i.e. if it's not `retain`ed then the *count* is not increased...

> Wouldn't it simplify things a lot with regards to keeping references at class levels? Wouldn't it reduce common traps cause by GC'ed view controllers?

I'm not 100% sure I understand your point. Can you back this up with an example ?

Comment: In the case of a local controller instance where the controller's view gets added to another view as a subview, the controller might get collected. This is a typical trap in Monotouch. If the view held a ref, this wouldn't happen.